# Perl DBI Return install_driver(Oracle) failed

Tags: oracle, perl

I have a problem when I using the Padre IDE to write a Perl script as

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:host=localhost;sid=orcl;port=1521', 'user', 'password', { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0 });
```

It raises this error

```
*install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't locate loadable object for module DBD::Oracle in @INC (@INC contains:D:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib D:/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/libD:/Dwimperl/perl/lib .) at (eval 54) line 3
Compilation failed in require at (eval 54) line 3.
Perhaps a module that DBD::Oracle requires hasn't been fully installedat test.pl line 19*
```

But if I manually run the two-line Perl script in a command it runs successfully.

Comment: Is Padre using it's own version of Perl?  Check which library is getting loaded before the DBI->connect by inspecting %INC.  If you have different files for DBI, they you are probably using two different Perl installs on your Windows box (and you'll have to install DBD::Oracle for the second one).

Comment: I found that if I execute that Perl script by using command:
    Perl test.pl    
Then, the error will not appear.
I have include DBI and DBD Oracle in lib folder for strawberry Perl, but it seems not working when I execute it when using Padre IDE.

Comment: Try C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin>perl -e "use DBD::Oracle;" and see what you get.  I suspect that DBD::Oracle is not installed at all or not properly if you indeed installed Padre from the DWIM distribution.  DBD::Oracle does not come with DWIM even though Strawberry Perl is installed with DWIM.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this version of Strawberry Perl, which now ships with DBD::Oracle.

http://strawberryperl.com/release-notes/5.20.0.1-64bit.html

Be sure to read the notes on this site concerning the Oracle client and PATH setup.

HTH